# Safari Web Inspector - Long string values truncated

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-web-inspector

In Safari (9.1), I am looking at a long string value (should be about 500 characters), but only shows me the first hundred or so followed by "...".

I think it's just a local setting because I have another machine running safari and I can see more on it.  I can't find it nor anything in the Google.

Thanks!

Comment: I work around this by right clicking on the variable and selecting LOG VALUE.  This writes the value to the console log.

Comment: I am not able to find LOG VALUE option on right click in safari

Answer (score -10, accepted):

**If you log the value to console or copy it (Cmd-C or using right-click context menu), it will not be truncated.**

In many places, Web Inspector needs to truncate values at some point so that the user interface remains, well, "usable" for sites with lots of long strings or few line breaks.

Comment: It copies truncated string without three dots at the end.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with Safari 13.0.2 where the log messages were cut short. But it only cuts messages if the message is not the first argument of the log function:

`console.log('first log string', 'second log string')`

The first argument will not (never?) be shortened. The second however will be truncated to about a 100 characters.

So if you have access to the code which does the logging, put everything inside the first argument and you should see the whole messages.

`console.log('first log string' + 'second log string')`

Comment: You are the King

Comment: But it trunctaes if you console log an object too. When you expand it any attribute with a long string is truncated. You should at least be able to hover over it to view it.

Comment: Well the question and answer only cover strings and not arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the string and select "Log value". This will print the full string to the console.

Comment: Thank you!!. This is the easiest, least instrusive answer

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue in safari, my array size was upto 2lakh and safari was only showing first 99 indexes. But my target was first 512 indexes so I used `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray.slice(0, 512)));`